# tem como utilizar variavel php dentro das funções

Tags: php

A minha duvida é o seguinte, eu consigo utilizar uma variavel que foi definida fora de uma função dentro de uma função?
exemplo se eu criar uma variavel telefone para receber os dados via form e declarar ela, eu posso uitlizar essa mesma variavel com este valor que foi inserido no formulario dentro da minha função?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para responder a sua dúvida é necessário primeiro entender o que é ***escopo de variáveis***.

> O escopo de uma variável é o contexto onde ela foi definida. No PHP a maior parte das variáveis possui escopo somente local.

Tipos de escopo no PHP:

- **local**: o escopo de uma variável é o contexto onde foi definida. A maioria das variáveis do PHP tem somente escopo local. Este escopo local inclui os arquivos incluídos e requeridos.
- **global**: declarada fora de qualquer função e acessada de qualquer
  lugar (dentro de funções usando “global $var”)
- **static**: igual a variável local, mas mantém seu valor depois que a função é encerrada.
- **parameter** – Igual a variável local, mas com seus valores passados
  como argumentos para a função.

Exemplo de escopo local:

```
<?php
$a = 10; // local
echo $a;
```

Exemplo de escopo global:

```
<?php
$a = 5; // Global

function minhaFuncao() {
    global $a;
    echo $a; // Global
}

minhaFuncao();
```

Obs: variaties globais podem ser acessadas dentro das funções ao adicionar a esquerda da variável a palavra **global**. Já fora da função basta informar o nome da variável (ex: $var)

Exemplo passando uma variável local como parâmetro para a função:

```
<?php
$a = 5; // local

function minhaFuncao($a) {
    echo $a; // local, aqui é outra variável diferente
}

minhaFuncao($a);
```

Obs: em `minhaFuncao($a)` eu poderia dá qualquer nome a variável, pois ela só existe no escopo local da função.

Para maiores informações e exemplos para os demais escopos consultar a documentação oficial: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0):

A maioria das variáveis do PHP tem somente escopo local.

Caso você deseje usar uma variável definida fora de uma função, a maneira mais fácil é passar ela via parâmetro, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
$a = 'ola!';

function teste($parametro) {
 echo $parametro;
}

teste($a);
```

Imprimirá na tela:

```
ola!
```